# Non destructive split in Ruby

Tags: ruby, string, split

I want to split the string `"hello+world-apple+francisco-rome"`, into `["hello", "+world", "-apple", "+francisco", "-rome"]`.

[`String::split`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M000803) actually loses the splitting element. Anyone can do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with this simple regular expression:

```
"hello+world-apple+francisco-rome".scan(/[+\-]?\w+/)
```

Comment: @Julien Genestoux: Here's a neat little trick: if you put the `-` first in the character class, then you don't need to escape it: `/[-+]/`. (Also works for `]`, I believe.)